# Prolog recursion not working as intended

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, reverse

I have to write a function that filters out palindromes from a given list (palindrome are words which are the same in reverse like abba)

```
palindroom([], []).
palindroom([X|Xs], Y):-
   (  atom_chars(X, Z),
      reverse(Z, K),
      atom_chars(D,K),
      atom_chars(P,Z),
      D==P,
      palindroom(Xs,[P|Y])
   ; 
      palindroom(Xs,Y)
   ).
```

I make the list elem into char array then reverse it and make it back into a string then compare the two, if it is I add it Y.

Here is my stacktrace where everything is going correctly until:

```
[trace] 44 ?- palindroom(["abba"],  X).
Call: (7) palindroom(["abba"], _G5269) ? creep
Call: (8) atom_chars("abba", _G5351) ? creep
Exit: (8) atom_chars("abba", [a, b, b, a]) ? creep
Call: (8) lists:reverse([a, b, b, a], _G5363) ? creep
Exit: (8) lists:reverse([a, b, b, a], [a, b, b, a]) ? creep
Call: (8) atom_chars(_G5386, [a, b, b, a]) ? creep
Exit: (8) atom_chars(abba, [a, b, b, a]) ? creep
Call: (8) atom_chars(_G5386, [a, b, b, a]) ? creep
Exit: (8) atom_chars(abba, [a, b, b, a]) ? creep
Call: (8) abba==abba ? creep
Exit: (8) abba==abba ? creep
Call: (8) palindroom([], [abba|_G5269]) ? creep
Fail: (8) palindroom([], [abba|_G5269]) ? creep
Redo: (7) palindroom(["abba"], _G5269) ? creep what is happening here? and why?
Call: (8) palindroom([], _G5269) ? creep
Exit: (8) palindroom([], []) ? creep
Exit: (7) palindroom(["abba"], []) ? creep
X = [].
```

I have another program with the same problem, could anyone help me? is the base of the recursion wrong or smt?

**EDIT!!**
got it working with

```
palindrome(Xs) :-
  reverse(Xs, Xs).

cycle([],[]).
cycle([X|Xs], Y):-
  atom_chars(X,Z),
  palindrome(Z),
  Y = [X|K],
  cycle(Xs,K);
  cycle(Xs,Y).
```

I misunderstood recursion in Prolog afterall. thanks @repeat and @lurker

Comment: @lurker I have a list on strings, which this program checks if its elements (["abba","pizza","tomato"] = ["abba"]) are palindrome and only returns palindromes as a result

Comment: OK, I'm sorry I misunderstood. You should probably consider having a predicate `palindrome/1` that succeeds only if its argument is a palindrome. Then have a separate predicate that iterates through your list and checks each using `palindrome/1` and includes it in the new list if it succeeds,.or use `findall/3` with the condition that, `(member(W, WordLilst), palindrome(W))`.

Answer (score 2):

How about defining `palindrome/1` like this, using the widely available list predicate `reverse/2`?

```
palindrome(Xs) :-
   reverse(Xs, Xs).
```

Sample queries:

```
:- palindrome([a,b,b,a]).
true.

:- palindrome([a,b,X,Y]).
X = b, Y = a.
```

Last, let's not forget about the most general query!

```
?- palindrome(Xs).
  Xs = []
; Xs = [_A]
; Xs = [_A,_A]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_A]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_B,_A]
; Xs = [_A,_B,_C,_B,_A]
...
```

Comment: this might work, but do you have any tips for me why I cannot return the list Z like I want to. I really would like to know what I am doing wrong? ( the implementation aside, maybe I am doing something generally wrong with recursions in prolog) @repeat

Comment: @DarkFeud see my comments to your original post. You should make an attempt at a recursive `palindromes(List, Palindromes)` predicate using the `palindrome/1` predicate that repeat is showing here.

Comment: @lurker. Seems I solved the wrong problem, not the one presented by the OP, but **the right one**:)